# How to set the host header in playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have a need to be able to change the host header for a url. I've tried setting extra headers but I keep getting an invalid argument error.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright    

def get_title():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:

        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        context = browser.new_context(
            user_agent="testing",
        )
        context.set_extra_http_headers({"host": "example.com"})
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto(url="http://111.222.333.444", wait_until="domcontentloaded")

        title = page.inner_html(selector="title")

        context.close()
        browser.close()

        return title
```

Setting the header to the page or the context give the same error. Is it possible to set the host header with playwright?

Answer (score 1):

Chromium will not allow you to override the `Host` header. I presume this is because `Host` is something the browser manages internally. [Source](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/b2254b38369f4f8ce8685b7a82dee1251f6cea22/services/network/url_loader.cc#L679-L683).

Why do you want to modify this header?

Comment: The service I'm wanting to test has a load balancer infront of the web servers, I'm wanting to target a web server directly with its IP then set the host header to the website I want.